# ASP.NET MVC Route Help, 2 routes, 1 with a category url structure and the other for content page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need some help with ASP.NET MVC routes.  I need to create 2 routes for a cms type application.  One route will be for category level URLS, and the other route will be for the actual page content.

- categories, always ends in a '/'

  ```
  www.example.com/category/
  www.example.com/category/subcategory/
  www.example.com/category/subcategory/subsubcategory/
  ```
- content page, doesn't end in a '/', can only be at the root level or after 1 subcategory page.

  ```
  www.example.com/root-level-page
  www.example.com/category/some-page-name
  ```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Routing does not distinguish between URLs ending with a / and URLs that don't end in /.